# Find and delete duplicate edges in OrientDb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Consider we have Vertex User and Edge FriendsWith. 
FriendsWith can be in both directions out and in (usually it is either out or in between 2 users).

Duplicates are when either out or in from one user to another is found more then one time (out and in together is not considered as duplicate)

Is there any way to find duplicate edges and delete them?

**UPDATE** Added picture illustrating problem

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: can be usefull for you a JavaScript function?

Comment: sure, javascript will be good too

Comment: for the future you can add a unique index for edges so same label edge duplicates are not allowed between two vertices

Comment: yes thats what I intended to do but found duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is my javascript function:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var C=g.command('sql','select from FriendsWith');
var arr = new Array(C.length);
var toRemove = new Array();

for(i=0;i<C.length;i++){
  var found = false;
  for (x = 0; x < i+1 && !found; x++) {
  if (arr[x] === C[i].getProperty("out").getId()+" "+C[i].getProperty("in").getId()) {
    found = true;
    toRemove.push(C[i].getId());
    }
  }
  arr[i] = C[i].getProperty("out").getId()+" "+C[i].getProperty("in").getId();
}

for(a=0;a<toRemove.length;a++){
  var C=g.command('sql','delete edge '+toRemove[a]);
}
```

Hope it helps.
Bye

Comment: thank you for reply but there can be performance issues because we got more than 600 000 vertices and 800 000 edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this function

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var friends=g.command("sql","select from FriendsWith");
var paths=[];
for(i=0;i<friends.length;i++){
    paths.push(friends[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
    var myEdge=paths[i];
    var vIn=myEdge.getProperty("in").getId();
    var vOut=myEdge.getProperty("out").getId();
    for(j=0;j<paths.length;j++){
        if(i<j){
            var edge=paths[j];
            var vInCopy=edge.getProperty("in").getId();
            var vOutCopy=edge.getProperty("out").getId();
            if((vIn==vInCopy && vOut==vOutCopy) || (vIn==vOutCopy && vOut==vInCopy)){
                g.command("sql","delete edge FriendsWith where @rid="+edge.getId());
                paths.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: seems what I need but is there any way to optimize it because I got more than 800 000 edges already

Comment: Can you send me your db for a test or a subset ?

Comment: it is more than 2GB and takes 2-3 hours for deploying.there is some real data

Comment: My goal is to replicate your database,
have you got many duplicate edges on few verteces or the duplicate edges are distributed on many vertices?

Comment: as far as I know - the duplicate edges are distributed on many vertices.

Answer (score 2):

I created a small DB to try your case. This is my code:

```
create class User extends V
create class follows extends E

create property User.id integer
create property User.name String

create vertex User set id=1, name="Paul"
create vertex User set id=2, name="John"
create vertex User set id=3, name="Mark"
create vertex User set id=4, name="Robert"

create edge follows from (select from User where id=1) to (select from User where id=2)
create edge follows from (select from User where id=2) to (select from User where id=1)
create edge follows from (select from User where id=1) to (select from User where id=3)
create edge follows from (select from User where id=2) to (select from User where id=3)
create edge follows from (select from User where id=3) to (select from User where id=2)
create edge follows from (select from User where id=3) to (select from User where id=4)
```

Graph:

[image]

Then I created a simple Javascript function which deletes, once found a duplicated edge, the in-direction edge.

Input: ridA (yout starting @rid)

Code:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var outF=g.command('sql','select expand(out("follows")) from '+ridA);
var inF=g.command('sql','select expand(in("follows")) from '+ridA);
for(x=0;x<outF.length;x++){
  var ridOut=outF[x].getId();
  for(y=0;y<inF.length;y++){
    var ridIn=inF[y].getId();
    if(ridOut==ridIn){
      g.command('sql','delete edge follows from '+ridIn+' to '+ridA);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

For example, if you try to delete the duplicated edges from the vertex #12:1, after having launched the function the two in-direction edges 'follow' will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is slightly different from what I need.
I need to find duplicates for ridOut (from #12:0 to #12:1 2 or more times) or ridIn not for ridOur == ridIn.

Comment: Hi, do you want to delete multiple edges from a single starting vertex, right ?

Comment: only duplicates which can occur in both directions

Comment: Hi, I tried the function after having created 4 duplicates of the edge 'follows' from vertex #12:1 (8 total edges) to 4 different vertices and the function deletes the duplicates. I used ridOut == ridIn because if they point to the same vertex it means that there's a duplicate. Once found it, it deletes only the 'IN' direction but the ‘OUT’ edge still remains (but you can also choose to preserve the 'OUT' direction). Summarizing, the deletion of the edges is from 1 (ridA) to N vertices, isn't it what you're looking for ?

Comment: I need to delete edges where ridOut, ridIn or (ridIn, ridOut) occurs more than 1 time

Comment: So you don't accept the same direction edge from/to a vertex but there could be IN and OUT edge of the same type/class on a vertex, right ?

Comment: Yes. I've added the picture illustrating my problem